# flex dynamic height fit image

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Need to fit **img** into dynamically calculated height of **li** due to **flex**. Currently it takes **all height, and pull height content**. Image should just fit into dynamically calculated height of LI, e.g. 50px and fit into it.

No hardcoded height is needed. Page should be 100% in any device. header/footer - flex: 1, main - flex: 3.

```css
body,
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body,
.root {
  height: 100%;
}

.root {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

main {
  flex: 3;
  background: lightyellow;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}

ul li {
  flex: 1;
  background: aliceblue;
  outline: 1px solid #000;
  display: flex;
  /* align-items: center; */
  justify-content: space-between;
}

img {
  /* object-fit: contain; */
}

header,
footer {
  flex: 1;
}

header {
  background: lightgray;
}

footer {
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="root">
  <header>
    HEAD
  </header>

  <main>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200" />
        <span>text</span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200" />
        <span>text</span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200" />
        <span>text</span>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </main>

  <footer>
    FOOTER
  </footer>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/sefb3o95/18/

Answer (score 1):

The main thing to make this work is to use Flexbox all the way.

Simply put, one need to nest flex parent/child instead of using `height: 100%`, to make use of Flexbox's own properties making its flex children stretch/fill their parents, and the reason is that `height: 100%` is not gonna work properly.

Additionally, having the `img` as a flex item will cause you some cross browser issues, so wrap it and give it a `max-height: 100%`, and it will size properly.

*See my notes in the CSS. The `min-height: 0` fix for Firefox is well explained here:*

- [*Why don't flex items shrink past content size?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36247140/why-dont-flex-items-shrink-past-content-size/36247448)

---

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/622ftLcL/7/)

Stack snippet

```css
body,
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body,
.root {
  height: 100%;
}

.root {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

main {
  flex: 3;
  background: lightyellow;
  display: flex;                 /*  added  */
  flex-direction: column;        /*  added  */
  min-height: 0;                 /*  added, Firefox need this  */
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 0;                 /*  added, Firefox need this  */
}

ul li {
  flex: 1;
  background: aliceblue;
  outline: 1px solid #000;
  display: flex;
  /* align-items: center; */
  justify-content: space-between;
  min-height: 0;                 /*  added, Firefox need this  */
}

img {
  max-height: 100%;              /*  added  */
}

header,
footer {
  flex: 1;
}

header {
  background: lightgray;
}

footer {
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="root">
  <header>
    HEAD
  </header>

  <main>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <span>
          <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200" />
        </span>
        <span>text</span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span>
          <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200" />
        </span>
        <span>text</span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span>
          <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200" />
        </span>
        <span>text</span>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </main>

  <footer>
    FOOTER
  </footer>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! It works on Chrome now, but doesn't work on Safari - iOS 10.3.3. Actually I need to make it work there....

Comment: @AlexIvasyuv Don't have access to Safari now. Can you send a screen shot?

Comment: @AlexIvasyuv Does this work in Safari? https://jsfiddle.net/622ftLcL/9/

Comment: It works on macOS on Safari v11.0.3, if add max-width: 100%; to img. But still not work on mobile Safari on iOS.

Comment: @AlexIvasyuv Can you test if this works in Safari 10: https://jsfiddle.net/622ftLcL/24/

Comment: @AlexIvasyuv Another option, based on the fact that the images should adjust to the first `span`'s height, you could also use `background-image` on it: https://jsfiddle.net/622ftLcL/27/

Comment: The primary issue in Safari is the use of `max-height: 100%` on the `img`. Safari is quite strict in requiring parent elements to have a specified `height` reference when the child has a percentage height. Flex heights and min/max heights are not enough. Safari requires the 
 `height` property. More details in the following post. In particular, see the paragraph right before the **Solutions** section: https://stackoverflow.com/q/33636796/3597276

Comment: @Michael_B Thank you very much...and plus 1 on that link's answer.

Comment: @AlexIvasyuv If you check Michael's comment above, and follow that link, you get an explanation why it won't be that simple to make Safari play along. The option I gave in a previous comment, using `background-image`, will likely be your best workaround. Let me know if I should add that to my answer.